# Ignoring files in Projectile

Tags: projectile

After googling and being recommended `projectile` as project navigation, I ended up trying that. I'm now frustrated by the lack of tutorials and/or explanations on how it works, so I was hoping somebody here knew how to handle it. Here is my current problem:

[image]

I can't understand how to use the `.projectile` file. Now, it works in my other project, but here is just completely fails to ignore files. I've tried `C-c p i` to clear countless times.

How does projectile work, and why doesn't the file actually ignore those files? And as a sidenote, could anyone recommend anything more reliable than projectile, if this is just how unreliable it is?

Comment: As @glucas says in his solution, projectile is very very stable for me too. You just need to have it configured right. I use `ag` for almost any search function. So I let `ag` do the file list generation using [this config](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/c7da9469e9de3aff83e3e3b09596ef3665b5ab95/setup-files/setup-projectile.el#L64-L77). If you are not familiar with `ag`, you set the files to ignore in `.agignore`. The plus is that I maintain just one `.agignore` file that is used in regular `ag` searches + projectile.

Comment: I have updated the question title. Feel free to revert it if the edit reflects a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ignore files matching a pattern, such as files with a specific extension, you need to include a wildcard in the pattern.

For example:

```
-*.swp
-*.meta
```

There are some examples of this on the project page in Github, in the [section on "Ignoring Files"](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/doc/projects.md#ignoring-files).

I've used Projectile daily for a while and in my experience it has always been very stable. Of course, as with any Emacs package you'll need to decide what best fits your work flow; and you may need to tweak configurations to suit your needs.

**Update**

From the comments, note that file ignore patterns are only working when using native indexing. This may be a bug when using alien indexing.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but this doesn't work for me either. The line `-*.meta` ignores neither the file `Test.meta` nor the file `Test.cs.meta`. I've saved the `.projectile` file, and invalidated the cache, and still projectile tries to find both these files. Interestingly, what *does* work is ignoring a specific file, as in `-/whatever.txt`.

Comment: What version of projectile? It's also worth testing with `projectile-find-file` rather than helm, in case the behavior is different there. You can call `projectile-find-file` with a prefix arg to invalidate the cache first.

Comment: Version `20150911.844`, and I'm using stock `projectile-find-file`. I should probably find my way over to the projectile bug tracker and see if there's something about this.

Comment: Just testing a bit myself (same version). It looks like a file extension pattern ("-*.meta") is working for me with `projectile-indexing-method` set to `'native`, but otherwise not.

Comment: I just tested it, and it was the same for me as well - it only works when set to native. On the github page they say that it's slower than alien, but I hope it's not super slow in comparison. But hey, it works!

Answer (score 3):

You should add a "/" before your items, like:

```
-/.meta
-/.projectile
```

This is the source code:

```
(defun projectile-paths-to-ignore ()
  "Return a list of ignored project paths."
  (-non-nil (--map (and (string-prefix-p "/" it)
                        ;; remove the leading /
                        (substring it 1))
                   (cdr (projectile-parse-dirconfig-file)))))
```

We must put a "/" before the items to make them to be valid.

Also, it uses string-prefix-p to check the file. If you want to ignore the files recursively, you can replace string-prefix-p with string-match-p.

```
(defun projectile-remove-ignored (files)
  "Remove ignored files and folders from FILES.

Operates on filenames relative to the project root."
  (let ((ignored (append (projectile-ignored-files-rel)
                         (projectile-ignored-directories-rel))))
    (-remove (lambda (file)
               (or (--any-p (string-prefix-p it file) ignored)
                   (--any-p (string-suffix-p it file) projectile-globally-ignored-file-suffixes)))
             files)))
```